# New document class not added correctly

Tags: lyx, document-classes

I'm pretty new to Latex and Lyx I'm having an issue while adding a new document class. 
Having the .cls file, I followed the steps like in here: https://www.paulkiddie.com/2010/02/adding-custom-class-files-cls-to-lyx-in-windows-vista-windows-7-environment/ .

The class is already available. It should have some theorems, definitions etc. When I create a document that has this class there are no theorems, definitions etc available... After I try to view the document, there appear some errors, but when I get to see it anyway it shows something that was in fact taken from the class (custom chapter beginnings).

Can anyone help me how to correctly add a new document class? Or maybe there are some issues with my class and I should make some changes to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to use your class in only one directory, put that class file into that directory. Otherwise, put it inside your `texmf` tree.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the underlying TeX distribution and the O.S.?